# Fit logistic model with nominal and ordinal predictors in R

Tags: r

I am trying to fit logistic regression in R where my response is whether 
the student is under probation or not, and my six independent variables are :

```
x1 = gender(male,female) which is nominal.
x2 = Hour spend in family activity (0 hour, <5 hour, 5-9 hour, 10-14 hour, 
>14 hour)
x3 = number of times under probation
x4 = types of school(public, private, other)
x5 = level of attendance in class( 70%, 70-79%, 80-89%, 90-99%, 100%)
x6 = hours of library work (0 hour, <5 hour, 5-9 hour, 10-14 hour, >14 hour)
```

my problem is that i have mixed of nominal and ordinal, does anyone can help how to fit this model in R?

Comment: Go ahead and try modelling everything with `glm`, it'll expand the nominal variables automatically. see `?glm`. Otherwise, if you would like something more explicit, take a look at one-hot-encoding. https://blog.datascienceheroes.com/how-to-use-recipes-package-for-one-hot-encoding/

Comment: yes i did that but when i interpreter my result the problem come.

Comment: ah, the problem was with the interpretation? What was the problem?

Comment: when i do glm() directly , the nominal and ordinal predictors were treated as numerical value ,

Comment: ok... maybe try the following: For the ordinal values, make sure that their factors make sense for the order you would like. If not, then look at this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/vignettes/forcats.html. For the nominal ones, go ahead and explode those out using one-hot encoding, or even something as simple as `tidyr::spread()`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your variables to each type that you want, for this case:

```
x1 = factor(x1, levels = c("male", "female")) #nominal
x2 = factor(x2, levels = c("0 hour", "<5 hour", "5-9 hour", "10-14 hour", 
     ">14 hour"), ordered = TRUE) #ordinal
x3 #stay_numeric
x4 = factor(x4, levels = c("public", "private", "other"))  #nominal
x5 = factor(x5, levels = c("70%", "70-79%", "80-89%", "90-99%", "100%"), 
     ordered = TRUE) #ordinal
x6 = factor(x6, levels = c("0 hour", "<5 hour", "5-9 hour", "10-14 hour", ">14 hour"), ordered = TRUE) #ordinal
```

Then you can fit those variables to the model using `glm` library, it will expand the levels or the categories of the variables automatically.